# Problem with import CSV files to QGIS 2.0.1

Tags: qgis, csv, wgs84

I have a problem with import CSV files to QGIS 2.0.1. I have a file with WGS84 coordinates it looks that:

```
Nr;Longitude;Latitude
1;18,06,23.66;54,83,12.50
2;18,08,81.30;54,73,09.30
3;18,23,47.62;54,83,11.77
4;18,28,25.92;54,79,56.37
5;18,19,08.39;54,75,02.55
6;18,39,31.49;54,72,78.02
7;18,43,98.37;54,63,70.36
8;18,56,39.86;54,48,10.63
9;18,02,12.36;54,77,67.14
10;18,19,55.17;54,83,17.04
11;18,45,62.00;54,66,41.40
```

QGIS import only the eight line. I don't know why? Every line looks the same

Here is this CSV files:

wyslijto.pl/download/i4f3gk2cum

Has anyone idea what's going on? Maybe it's problem with coding?

Comment: Are the coordinates supposed to be in DMS format?

Comment: Yes, the coordinates should be in DMS format. Maybe QGIS don`t read those format because it isn`t the DMS format. DNS format should have max 60d60m60s. I see that ther is more than 60m and 60s. QGIS don`t convert automatically to DMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS usually works with decimal degrees.

QGIS 2.0.1 now can also handle DMS format, but your data seems to have more than 60 minutes or degrees, or is already in decimal format but mal-formatted.

If you change the first comma to point, and delete the second comma and the decimal point, the data gets loaded (without checking DMS), and it looks not too badly placed:

[image]